# Not able to start update manager on Ubuntu12.10

Tags: ubuntu, updates

Recently I updated to Ubuntu 12.10 But now I am not able to launch update manager. Whenever I try to launch it I see the following error on console.

```
(update-manager:4686): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'com.ubuntu.update-notifier' is not installed
```

I installed update-manager also but still I have getting this issue. I don't know the reason.

***Edit***
I assumed that installing update-manager will fix this issue, and didn't realize that there is seperate application call update-notifier. Once I installed that my issue got fixed.

```
sudo apt-get install update-notifier
```

Comment: same thing in ubuntu 18.04